# Laravel 404 Page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am looking for 404 page for particular controller.Right now if id not found then it loads 404 page from `App\Exceptions\Handler`.But now problem is i need to show different 404 page for particular controller .Is There a way to override 404 exception in particular controller

```
if($request->segment(3)==null){

return view('errors.newerror');
} else {

return view('dataview');
}
```

I tried above code but its showing handler 404 page

**Updated**

```
if($request->segment(3)==null)
{
return abort(sat_error); //return abort('sat_error');
}else{
        echo '<img alt="" src="'.$url.'">';
        }
```

I have tried above method but still its loading default 404

Comment: try to see this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#custom-http-error-pages) is this what you want ?

Comment: where is your sat_error located?

Comment: @Cannot.resources/views/errors/

Comment: I would double check the condition. Try returning `return abort(sat_error);` without the condition and see what happens

Comment: if my ul localhost/learn/my/1 is then its exicuting else if i remove one from that url i mean  localhost/learn/my/ then its showing handler 404

Comment: `$request->segment(3)` is looking for the third url segment in your case the first url has `learn/my/1`  i.e `learn= segment(1), ... 1 = segment(3)` thats why it runs now the second one doesnt have the 3rd segment so u run into 404 handler

Comment: @CannotFindSymbol.sorry that is my typo error

Comment: is your issue fixed?

Comment: @CannotFindSymbol.no

Answer (score 2):

```
return abort(404);
```

view in

```
resources/views/errors/404.blade.php
```

Comment: @IIya.Thanks but its not working for me.i have updated question